# AngularJS: ng-click in directive not firing on mobile

Tags: jquery, angularjs, mobile

i'm currently struggling with the ng-click in AngularJS.

I have a directive and inside an element with and ng-click-command.

```
<div class="james-upload-wrapper row">
<div class="james-upload-image" ng-show="room.image">
    <img src="{{room.image}}" />
</div>
<div class="james-upload-title twelve columns" ng-init="form.showInput=false;">
    <div class="ten columns">
        <span class="james-upload-title" ng-hide="form.showInput">{{room.name}}</span>
        <input class="text input" ng-model="room.name" ng-show="form.showInput" />
    </div>
    <div class="two columns">
        <a class="james-upload-button james-icon-pencil" ng-click="form.showInput = !form.showInput"></a>
        <a class="james-upload-button james-icon-upload" ng-click="openFileUpload()"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I click that with normal Chrome window, everything works great. If I emulate a Nexus 7 view with Developer Tools, nothing happens. I'm using AngularJS 1.2.16 with jQuery 1.11.1.

I included ngTouchin my app dependencies, but it doesn't work, wether I include it or not...

I hope you guys have some ideas.

Regards