# data-ng-click mobile not tapable

Tags: html, angularjs, mobile, angularjs-ng-click

So, I have a problem with button, which is clickable and works perfectly on any browser, but, I can't make it tapable anywhere on mobile.

However, you still can tap it, but you should hold it long, until your phone is selecting the text on it.

I assume that problem is in Angular and data-ng-click directive, however, I might be not right.

Here is the jade for the button

```
button.btn.btn--full(type="submit", data-ng-click="ctrl.submit", data-ng-disabled="ctrl.processing") {{ ctrl.processing ? 'Please wait...' : 'Continue' }}
```

Probably, there is an answer somewhere already, but I've tried everything I could found (spend a lot of time on googling this issue).

The button is not overlaying with any other element. And works perfectly on the browser with the same window width as mobiles.

I tried the following (probably not listing all I've tried, because I don't remember everything already):
1. (stupid, but anyway) tried to change data-ng-click to ng-click
2. tried custom directive like that   [ng-click and ng-touch mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813080/ng-click-and-ng-touch-mobile-device)
3. that's not a 300ms delay, because nothing happens after this time. Anyway, I tried touch-action: manipulation;
4. and tried to prevent scrolling on tap when the button is clicked
5. change "button" to "a"

Nothing works, so I'm giving up. Please, any ideas are appreciated. Thank you in advance, guys.

We're using

```
"angular": "~1.2.18",
"angular-touch": "^1.3.10",
```

no jQuery

Probably, a similar issue with no answer yet [AngularJS: ng-click in directive not firing on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701933/angularjs-ng-click-in-directive-not-firing-on-mobile)

P.S. I'm new to Angular.

Comment: Have a look at this answer. [ng-click and ng-touch mobile device](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25813263/2725210)